# Dynamically select the initial route name in react-navigate

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My app will have 4 main pages: A, B, C and Homepage

Before showing the **Homepage** the user will need to go through **A**, **B** and **C** (sequentially, using `react-navigation`) to collect some information. I will store the information in the device using `expo-secure-store`.

If the user completed all the steps, the next time the app will start I want to show directly the **Homepage** screen.

Considering that `SecureStore.getItemAsync` is async, I'm not able to query it when I'm starting my app:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {

  const data = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("pincode");
  var firstScreen = data ? "Homepage" : "A";
  /* alt solution - not working
  SecureStore.getItemAsync("data").then((data) => {
    firstScreen = data ? "Homepage" : "A";
  });
  */

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={firstScreen}>
        <Stack.Screen name="A" component={AScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="B" component={BScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="C" component={CScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Homepage" component={HomepageScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

If I use `await` *I get Unexpected reserved word 'await'*, while if I do it in an async way, the `firstScreen` value will be of course set to late.

Comment: You can show some loading screens while getting the data from expo secure storage. And async & await needs to be used together. Await requires async, but async doesn't require await.

Answer (score 1):

1. You want to put any State (so your `firstScreen` into react State with `useState`.
2. You want (for your 'problem') to initalise the state when the component is mounted. We useEffect with an open dep's array to handle that. As the state is held in SecureStore which we retrieve with an Async call I've written a function that will use Async/Await to retrieve this and populate the state when it is done.
3. As suggested above, you might want to show some form of Loading process so that users are not shown a page that is not ready yet!

Something like (BTW - you may want to lift this into a navigation component to keep your App component simple!):

```js
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const [firstScreen, setFirstScreen] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    SecureStore.getItemAsync("pincode").then(
      (data) => {
        setFirstScreen(data? 'Homepage' : 'A');
        setLoading(false);
      }
    ).catch((err) => {
        setLoading(false);        
        setFirstScreen('A');
    });
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return null; //Or something to show that you are still warming up!
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={firstScreen}>
        <Stack.Screen name="A" component={AScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="B" component={BScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="C" component={CScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Homepage" component={HomepageScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```